# How to use Windows fonts with memoir class

Tags: fonts, memoir, miktex, windows

I am writing my thesis using the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class within MiKTeX on Windows 7. However, I want to use some of the Windows fonts (e.g., `Cambria`). Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Yes, with XeTeX or LuaTeX you can use all system fonts.

Comment: Could you give me some example, please?

Comment: The `fontspec` package provides support for this in XeTeX and LuaTeX. Please consult its documentation. @Mario S. E. mentioned the two necessary commands in his answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per `fontspec` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) in LuaTeX and XeTeX, you could set this by using:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that I tried with:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Corbel}
\setmonofont{Myriad Pro}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color=000066]{Cambria Math}
% Symbol \perp is not defined in Cambria Math, so we fix this bug
\AtBeginDocument{\def\perp{\mathrel\bot}}

\begin{document}
Здравей.
\end{document}
```

I am using `TexStudio` with it's default command for `XeTeX`. `MikTex` is 32 bit on `Windows` 64bit.

Comment: I think that problem was with encoding of source file.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to use Windows (Open Type) fonts is to switch from `pdftex` engine to `xetex` or to `luatex`. I prefer `xetex` since MikTeX's `luatex` is extremely slow. Here is a working example from my current textbook:

```
\documentclass{...}% any class at your choice

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Corbel}
\setmonofont{Myriad Pro}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color=000066]{Cambria Math}
% Symbol \perp is not defined in Cambria Math, so we fix this bug
\AtBeginDocument{\def\perp{\mathrel\bot}}

\usepackage[english,ngerman,swedish,main=russian]{babel}
```

Then run `xelatex.exe` instead of `pdflatex.exe`. All `eps` graphics should be preliminarily converted to `pdf`.

Note that Cambria Math is the best math font fit for Cambria text font. Both Cambria text and Cambria Math come with Windows 7 as well as Corbel sans-serif font. Unfortunately there is no free good math pair for other text Open Type fonts included with Windows.

*That's all, folks!*

P.S. In general, it is recommended to use `polyglossia` package instead of `babel` when compiling your document under `luatex`/`xetex` if `babel` fails for your language.

Comment: I tried with your piece of code and it is working with english. But for other languages there is a problem.